# MouseLeftButtonUp does not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, mouseevent

I have a `Button`

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="share.png" 
                       MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                       MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

But the problem is that, unlike MouseLeftButtonDown, the event MouseLeftButtonUp does not fire. Why? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably because the `Button` is handling the event already, so it doesn't filter down to the Image control.

Why are you handling the MoustUp and MouseDown events on the `Image`? Why not handle them on the `Button`?

**EDIT**
After a quick look at the documentation for this event, I see that the routing strategy for [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is [Direct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies), but the actual underlying event is the [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event which has a [Bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) strategy. So, in effect, `MouseLeftButtonUp` should have a de-facto bubbling strategy, meaning the `Image` should have the opportunity to handle the event before the `Button`.

Sounds like something else might be going on. If you set the Image to nothing on the Image control, and the background is null (different from `Color.Transparent`), then WPF will treat the control as not "existing" as far as mouse events go.

**EDIT 2**
Hmm... maybe my original guess was correct afterall. According to this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/wpf/thread/e231919d-9fef-4aa5-9dcb-2c1eb68df25b/#306db880-ed50-45d2-819f-88d76f7148c1
`Button` is handling the `MouseUp` event. Try using [PreviewMouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup.aspx) and then checking to see which button was clicked.

**EDIT 3**
Ok... I think I figured it out. I'm betting that the Button is "capturing" the Mouse on the MouseDown event. When this occurs, other controls will not receive MouseUp or MouseDown events (include the Preview versions) until the Mouse has been released.
See: http://books.google.com/books?id=nYl7J7z3KssC&pg=PA146#v=twopage&q&f=true

Comment: I have to change the Image Source using these events. Even using Button event MouseLeftButtonUp  it does not work.

Comment: I believe that the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event is only called after `MouseUp`. Since the `Button` is probably setting the `IsHandled` property to `true` for `MouseUp`, `MouseLeftButtonUp` is probably never being raised. Trying handling `MouseUp` on the `Button`. (You may even need to handle `PreviewMouseUp` - not sure about the order the events are handled.)

Answer (score 5):

The Click event is handling the LeftMouseUp event as Cyborgx37 said.

You can use the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event instead of `MouseLeftButtonUp`, on Button as you can see below:

```
<Button PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="..." />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Your Button template only has an Image, I guess you don't need this Button, you can use as above, so you can capture the MouseLeftUp event.

```
<Image MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp" Source="..." />
```

This way is so much easier, but it depends on what you need.

*Btw, sorry for my crap english, I hope it could help you.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the event PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp.